# How to bind PprofileBase to DetailsView?

Tags: data-binding, datasource, umbraco, dataview, asp.net-profiles

I have a class *RM.Member* which extends Microsoft *ProfileBase* class.

I need to bind it to a DetailsView eg.

```
dvRegistration.DataSource = RM.Member.UserById(nodeId);
```

where *RM.Member.UserById(nodeId)* returns *RM.Member* type

I'm getting error

```
Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.
```

Not sure how I can make it working?

Answer (score 1):

look like you have type cast problem ...

your DetailsView control accepting list or IEnumerable ...as DataSource and you returning something else from your RM.Member.UserById method ....

its type mismatch ...

try to convert return type of UserById to list ... using .toList() or convert it to list